# Dynamic View lost on postback MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having a dropdown and on value change of dropdown, I am posting back to controller and creating view. Here is my Code.

```
 <div id="divPlans"></div>
```

Jquery on DropDownChange

```
  $("#ddlPlans").change(function () {
        var numberOfPlans = $(this).val();
        var data = { "id": numberOfPlans };
        $.ajax({
            url: "Plans",
            type: "POST",
            data: data, 
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {                 
                $("#divPlans").html(result);
            }
     });
});
```

Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Plans(int id)
    {
    var model = new ItemVM { NumOfplans = id, ListPlans = new List<Plan>() };
    for (var i = 0; i < id; i++)
    {
        model.Listlans.Add(new Plan
        {
             Name = "",
              Desciption = "",                    
        });
    }

   return View("Plan", model);
   }
```

After postback, if there is error in modelstate, I am losing the View.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: What do you want to retrun/display in  `<div id="divPlans"></div> ` ?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker Let say the select 1, means they enter name as  Plan 1 and description as Plan Description 1. So, I want to display those values in textboxes in <div>

Comment: How about adding a `if(ModelState.IsValid) {} else {}`

Comment: @gerdi Yes, I am doing it in else, but have to return two views

Comment: @Chatra: what do you mean by loosing view. Do you want , let say , after submitting form, if there is any validation error, then you want to show selected value in dropdown and corresponding div. ?

Comment: Your post does not summarize your question, still I think PartialViews can help you.

Comment: @AmitKumar, I want to show corresponding div on validation error